# 99% used memory, but 70% of unused allocated memory and 97% swap available: what can I do?

Tags: memory, memory-management, top

In a server with **48GB** of **RAM**, when I run `top`, I see that less than 500 MB are **free (1%)**, whereas when I sum up the column of % of **memory used** by each process, it is around **30%**.

Since only the **2.7%** of **swap** memory is used, can I safely run more processes, to claim back the allocated but unused memory from the system?

(I would like to be sure because I am not the only person using that server)

```
$ top

top - 13:49:07 up 100 days,  5:56,  2 users,  load average: 19.17, 19.27, 19.31
Tasks: 712 total,   4 running, 708 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 39.8%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 60.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65978420k total, 65511044k used,   467376k free,  2123640k buffers
Swap: 32767976k total,   885828k used, 31882148k free, 44048824k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                           
 2790 user1  25   0 4336m 3.9g 9992 R 100.0  6.2 171:14.27 python26                                                         
 2785 user1  25   0 4257m 3.8g 9992 R 100.0  6.1 171:23.51 python26                                                         
 2803 user1  25   0 4058m 3.6g 9992 R 100.0  5.8 171:05.19 python26                                                         
22269 root      18   0 1378m 348m  51m S 100.1  0.5 858:21.01 MATLAB                                                           
19745 root      18   0 1369m 344m  51m S 99.7  0.5 849:19.47 MATLAB                                                            
22901 root      18   0 1353m 339m  49m S 99.7  0.5 838:21.33 MATLAB                                                            
22511 root      18   0 1348m 322m  49m S 100.1  0.5 849:47.15 MATLAB                                                           
19517 root      18   0 1262m 318m  51m S 99.7  0.5 853:36.01 MATLAB                                                            
19295 root      18   0 1283m 314m  51m S 100.1  0.5 867:38.72 MATLAB                                                           
23042 root      18   0 1274m 306m  51m S 99.7  0.5 827:33.94 MATLAB                                                            
10289 root      18   0 1141m 305m 4764 S  0.3  0.5   2514:51 java                                                              
20767 root      18   0 1265m 303m  51m S 99.7  0.5 797:40.98 MATLAB                                                            
20382 root      18   0 1268m 302m  51m S 100.1  0.5 809:05.64 MATLAB                                                           
21956 root      18   0 1261m 298m  51m S 100.1  0.5 867:56.52 MATLAB                                                           
22743 root      18   0 1268m 287m  51m S 100.1  0.4 837:39.99 MATLAB                                                           
20180 root      18   0 1253m 280m  51m S 100.1  0.4 826:00.43 MATLAB                                                           
23526 root      18   0 1243m 271m  51m S 100.1  0.4 810:12.43 MATLAB                                                           
24176 root      18   0 1205m 240m  51m S 100.1  0.4 787:07.32 MATLAB                                                           
19060 root      19   0 1179m 233m  51m S 100.1  0.4 883:03.83 MATLAB                                                           
12401 root      20   0 16.3g 218m 4256 S  0.0  0.3 176:20.91 java                                                              
23825 root      18   0 1144m 205m  51m S 100.1  0.3 798:55.61 MATLAB                                                           
10210 root      34  19  381m 142m 1436 S  0.0  0.2   1:24.52 yum-updatesd                                                      
20569 root      19   0 16.3g  89m  16m S  5.3  0.1 648:46.29 java                                                              
23937 root      18   0 16.4g  85m  16m S  0.0  0.1 934:03.86 java                                                              
20438 root      19   0 16.3g  84m  16m S  0.0  0.1 638:23.89 java                                                              
20487 root      19   0 16.4g  82m  16m S  0.0  0.1 644:32.01 java                                                              
11877 root      17   0 16.4g  50m 5692 S  0.0  0.1   1491:55 java                                                              
10223 root      19   0 16.4g  50m 5180 S  0.0  0.1   1239:56 java
```

Comment: Memory in use is **a good thing**. Unused memory might as well be in a drawer rather than in a server. Any modern OS knows this an uses the 'spare' memory as disk cache, which means it will be used, yet it is available when a program needs it (the disk cache will simply shrink).

Comment: `to claim back the allocated but unused memory from the system?`. You can, but that is a bad thing. It will not add anything of value. If is likely to degrade performance.

Comment: So, based on what you are saying, I cannot run more processes like the three on top (`python26`), or I will either slow down everything or crash the server, right?

Comment: 1) Yes, you probably can. See [http://www.linuxatemyram.com/](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) for some background.  2) The *probably* is based on just the memory numbers. If another resource (e.g. disk, or CPU's) are already maxed out then no.